# How do I mount a pendant light with only a cord (no chain or metal tube)?

Tags: lighting, mounting

I would like to hang a glass pendant light to replace a light in my house. The box is good (I never had a problem with the old light and it looks fine on inspection) but I can't quite figure out how to get the new one up there. I have the cross piece, which connects to the canopy, but nowhere that I can see does it actually attach to the cord (see the attached picture). The cord simply goes through the piece to attach to the home wiring. I'm pretty sure I don't want the home wiring to hold the weight of the fixture (it's not super heavy, but it's not light either). There is no set screw in the canopy which could hold onto the cord. Is there some sort of collar with a set screw I can use around the cord? Am I supposed to tie a knot or some such thing?

Thanks in advance for the help.

[image]

Comment: Should be a threaded hole where the cord/wire goes into the lamp.  You do not use the cord to hang/hold weight.

Comment: That flat plate, of which we have a perfect edge-on view, should have a couple of holes in it that line up with threaded holes in the ceiling box. You should have a couple of screws that go through the plate and into those holes in the box and that's what holds the weight of the lamp. Please provide pics of the plate and the box ([edit] them into your post) for confirmation.

Comment: @FreeMan Yes, of course the flat plate has screw holes in it. That plate certainly attaches to the box and the canopy attaches to it. The issue is that the canopy and the plate have no connection to the cord or to the glass bell itself.

Answer (score 2):

So, I forgot to **zoom in** earlier.

[image]

My prime suspect now is that you simply need to loosen the barely seen setscrew on this part (or two if it has two) and slide it up until it will thread on to the nipple. There appears to be a setscrew just barely visible on the side, there appears to be a line indicating that this part is **not** attached to the lamp, and the treatment of the end of it facing the lamp matches the treatment of the part on the lamp with its clearly seen setscrew. They are a pair of cord-clamps - one on the lamp, one on the ceiling fixing. The one on the ceiling fixing whould thread onto the nipple and hold the cover in place.

Me, I'd still put a knot in the cord above the nipple, simply to keep from dropping the lamp and yanking the connections while threading this on and later removing it. But wait - what's this? A cable clamp so you don't have to tie a knot up there for that purpose, I do believe. Set your desired length, clamp that on the cable, connect wires and screw plate into box, slide the outside cable clamp up the cord, screw on to secure the cover and tighten setscrew to firmly grasp the cord.

[image]

If that doesn't turn out to be the case, the original (below) still applies.

Either

- The top-most nut causes compression of an o-ring that grabs the cord
  jacket (a cable gland)though this does not look quite right for that.

OR

- You tie a knot in the cord, such as the so-called [Underwriter's Knot.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwriter%27s_knot)

OR

- You replace that fitting with a cable gland/strain relief/cord grip.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the fixture should actually be supported by the cord and that the plate (of which we have a perfect edge-on view) isn't supposed to be screwed to the box to support the weight?

Comment: The plate is screwed to the box. The cord supports the fixture, the plate supports the cord. Hanging lamp cords are designed to do that. Heck, virtually everybody's dining room table lamp when I was growing up had a cord retractor reel so you could raise it up or pull it down to suit the number of diners and how far the table was pulled out.

Comment: Gotcha. That does make sense and identifies you, like me, as a child of the 70s. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, that thing that looks like a set screw on the upper piece (which is indeed separate from the lower one) is merely an artifact of the light reflecting badly in the photo (the bottom piece does have a set screw, which you can see). Also, that cord clamp up top is flimsy plastic, meaning that I don't really want to trust the weight of the lamp to it. I ended up buying some of these (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07VQXJBM9/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) from Amazon to screw into the cord up top. Do you think that'll be strong enough?

Comment: I think tying a knot in the cord above the tube (or using the flimsy clamp since that's apparently as designed and intended - or both for belt and suspenders) would be adequate, but those might also work - and I'd still knot the cord.

Answer (score 1):

Some lamps are designed to be suspended by their electrical cords (using appropriate cable also designed for that).   Other lamps are designed to be connected to the box ears via a cross bar or the box stud via a nipple.

Lamps suspended from cords usually have rubber cords, a canopy that is secured to the box, and either a knot or a clamp to suspend the cable from the canopy.  *You have a rubber cord but none of the other features of such a lamp*.

Lamps attached to the box usually have wires, not a rubber cord, run through the threaded pipe, and a way to attach the pipe to the lamp and to the box.  *You have a cord, not wires, you have a threaded pipe and a cross bar, but it's not clear if the pipe can be attached to the lamp.*

It is hard to be sure from your photos, but it looks like the lamp can be connected to the threaded pipe at the point where @ecnerwal drew a yellow box.  The threaded rod is connected to the cross bar and the cross bar connects to the box ears.  The cable, running through the pipe, should be completely slack, you should make a few loops with it where it exits the pipe at the top to allow the lamp to be raised and lowered and attached via the threaded rod.   You might need some kind of adapter to connect the rod to the lamp.

If that's wrong, if the top of the lamp is secured to the *cable* by compression and cannot be screwed onto the threaded rod, you should eliminate the threaded rod, and just use the cross bar to suspend the cord by tying a knot in the cord or attaching a plastic compression bushing above the cross bar.    Your canopy does not look like it was designed to perform this function.

Comment: There is clearly a canopy, and if the part in the yellow box is the cord clamp which threads to the nipple it secures the canopy to the box **and** is a cord clamp...so jumping to "you don't have these parts" seems a bit premature without some further input form the questioner.

Comment: For the canopy to support the lamp via the cord it would have to be attached to the box via box screws, and I don't see that here, it looks like the canopy is supported by a nut or the lamp threaded to the rod.  If the canopy and lamp are supported by the rod, then the cord plays no part in supporting anything.  Even if there's an integrated cord clamp, it has no role.    Of course further info might change/improve this answer! But I'm fairly confident in what I see here.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the answer and comments. I'm not totally sure I follow all of your points, but to clarify. There is a plate that attaches to the box in the ceiling. The threaded rod hanging from this has a hole that goes through the canopy. The piece below that threads onto the rod and supports the canopy. That's all good. The problem is that none of the previously-mentioned pieces attaches to the cord in any obvious way. There's no real compression clamp (just the flimsy plastic one you see) or anything else that's obvious to me.

Comment: Also, just so we're clear, these is no rod attached to the lamp. Only a rubber electrical cord.

Comment: You should follow the new detailed instructions in the answer from @Ecnerwal.  I think he has identified how this lamp was meant to be assembled.